# Formatting output in a report on SQL*Plus (after spool to CSV)

Tags: sql, oracle, report, sqlplus

I have a question about formatting the output in a report that I get from csv that was spooled from SQL*Plus.
I have Initial table whose data looks like this:

| ord_no | ls_prod_division | ls_prod_area | ls_prod_family_name | ls_prod_family_code | ls_prod_generic_name | ls_brand_name | ls_reference_prod | ls_description | ls_atc_code | ls_atc_desc | ls_indication | ls_ind_meddra_lvl | ls_ind_meddra_ver | ls_ind_meddra_code | ls_cindication | ls_psur_int_birthday | ls_dsur_int_birth_date | ls_eu_birth_date | ls_psur_reference_date | ls_psur_type | ls_psur_sub_freq_value | ls_psur_sub_freq_unit | ls_date_psur_start | ls_date_psur_end | ls_psur_subm_due_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | Medicinal Product | Aceclofenac |  | Aceclofenac | Aceclofenac 1.5% w/w cream |  |  | M01AB16 | aceclofenac | Analgesic & Anti-inflammatory |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1 |  | Medicinal Product | Aceclofenac |  | Aceclofenac | Aceclofenac 100 mg tablets |  |  | M01AB16 | aceclofenac | NSAIDS |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1 |  | Medicinal Product | Aceclofenac |  | Aceclofenac | Aceclofenac 100 mg tablets |  |  | M01AB16 | aceclofenac | Anti-inflammatory |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1 |  | Medicinal Product | Aceclofenac |  | Aceclofenac | Aceclofenac 100 mg tablets |  |  | M01 | ANTIINFLAMMATORY AND ANTIRHEUMATIC PRODUCTS | Antiinflammatory |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

And I am trying to format the report output of that table so I get it like this:

| ord_no | ls_prod_division | ls_prod_area | ls_prod_family_name | ls_prod_family_code | ls_prod_generic_name | ls_brand_name | ls_reference_prod | ls_description | ls_atc_code | ls_atc_desc | ls_indication | ls_ind_meddra_lvl | ls_ind_meddra_ver | ls_ind_meddra_code | ls_cindication | ls_psur_int_birthday | ls_dsur_int_birth_date | ls_eu_birth_date | ls_psur_reference_date | ls_psur_type | ls_psur_sub_freq_value | ls_psur_sub_freq_unit | ls_date_psur_start | ls_date_psur_end | ls_psur_subm_due_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | Medicinal Product | Aceclofenac |  | Aceclofenac | Aceclofenac 1.5% w/w cream |  |  | M01AB16 | aceclofenac | Analgesic & Anti-inflammatory |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1 |  |  |  |  |  | Aceclofenac 100 mg tablets |  |  | M01 | ANTIINFLAMMATORY AND ANTIRHEUMATIC PRODUCTS | NSAIDS |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Anti-inflammatory |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Antiinflammatory |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

I am using the following code:

```
set colsep '|'
set trimspool on
set termout off
set echo off
set trim on
set heading on
set feedback off
set linesize 32000
set trimout on
set pagesize 50000
set underline off
col ord_no format 99999
col ls_prod_area format a200
col ls_prod_family_name format a200
col ls_prod_family_code format a200
col ls_prod_generic_name format a200
col ls_brand_name format a200
col ls_reference_prod format a200
col ls_description format a200
col ls_atc_code format a200
col ls_atc_desc format a200
col ls_indication format a200
col ls_ind_meddra_lvl format a200
col ls_ind_meddra_ver format a200
col ls_ind_meddra_code format a200
spool export.csv
break on ls_prod_area on ls_prod_family_name on ls_prod_generic_name on ls_atc_code on ls_atc_desc on ls_brand_name on ls_indication

SELECT rpad(ord_no, 200, ' ') ord_no ,rpad(ls_prod_area, 200, ' ') ls_prod_area ,rpad(ls_prod_family_name, 200, ' ') ls_prod_family_name ,rpad(ls_prod_family_code, 200, ' ') ls_prod_family_code ,rpad(ls_prod_generic_name, 200, ' ') ls_prod_generic_name ,rpad(ls_brand_name, 200, ' ') ls_brand_name ,rpad(ls_reference_prod, 200, ' ') ls_reference_prod,rpad(ls_description, 200, ' ') ls_description ,rpad(ls_atc_code, 200, ' ') ls_atc_code ,rpad(ls_atc_desc, 200, ' ') ls_atc_desc ,rpad(ls_indication, 200, ' ') ls_indication ,rpad(ls_ind_meddra_lvl, 200, ' ') ls_ind_meddra_lvl ,rpad(ls_ind_meddra_ver, 200, ' ') ls_ind_meddra_ver ,rpad(ls_ind_meddra_code, 200, ' ') ls_ind_meddra_code 
from tmp_product_family
order by ord_no, ls_brand_name,LS_ATC_CODE, LS_ATC_DESC, LS_INDICATION, LS_IND_MEDDRA_LVL, LS_IND_MEDDRA_VER, LS_IND_MEDDRA_CODE ;
```

And I don't have a problem with output in CMD window, but with transforming the CSV to Excel via Excel's Data From Text/CSV tool.
I am putting custom delimiter which is set to '|'.

And for the first `ord_no` (1) first and second row that were transformed from CSV to Excel looks like this:

| ORD_NO | LS_PROD_AREA | LS_PROD_FAMILY_NAME | LS_PROD_FAMILY_CODE | LS_PROD_GENERIC_NAME | LS_BRAND_NAME | LS_REFERENCE_PROD | LS_DESCRIPTION | LS_ATC_CODE | LS_ATC_DESC | LS_INDICATION | LS_IND_MEDDRA_LVL | LS_IND_MEDDRA_VER | LS_IND_MEDDRA_CODE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Medicinal Product | Aceclofenac |  | Aceclofenac | Aceclofenac 1.5% w/w cream |  |  | M01AB16 | aceclofenac | Analgesic & Anti-inflammatory |  |  |  |
| 1 |  | Aceclofenac 100 mg tablets |  |  | M01 | ANTIINFLAMMATORY AND ANTIRHEUMATIC PRODUCTS | Antiinflammatory |  |  |  |  |  |  |

As you can see in second row all the values after the `ord_no` are shifted three columns to the left (e.g. `Aceclofenac 100 mg tablets` should be in `LS_BRAND_NAME` column).

Does anyone have any idea how to escape that problem.

Comment: To me, it looks like **reporting** problem. Any (decent) tool has an option to "break" result on certain column(s). Even if you ran that query in SQL*Plus, a command line non-GUI tool, you'd still have such an option. Is it worth the effort doing it in a SELECT statement? Where will that output be reviewed at the end?

Comment: Please do not ask the same question repeatedly (and delete the previous versions). If you are not getting a response then (1) improve the question (2) put a bounty on the quesiton.

Comment: @Littlefoot What do you mean by "break" result? I tried in Excel but it is too much work as I don't know to write Excel formulas for that complicated things easily. If you know any tool that could do what I need please refer me to it? I need the output for Excel table. I do not need to "break" result on columns but I need to merge them together as you can see on example in the question.

Comment: Your question is far too complicated as: you have not provided `CREATE TABLE` or `INSERT` statements for your sample input data (which means you expect us to reverse engineer your tables and data from the output); your query is huge, difficult to understand, and outputting lots of blank columns so you have not attempted to simplify the problem to make it easy to understand; and it looks like something you should solve when displaying the data and not when you query the database. Please [edit] the question to make it a [MRE].

Comment: @MTO How do you put a bounty on the question? And as far for the other comment, this is the minimal reproducible example for the smallest amount of data. CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements are really not important here as all the columns are mentioned both in tables and in select statement. INSERT of data is also not necessary as all the data is visible in example data (all the data is exactly the same in tables).

Comment: Of course the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements are important. If you do not provide them then you are expecting the people you want to assist you to provide them and that increases the burden on volunteers and makes it much more difficult to answer your question. Make it easy to answer the question and provide a [MRE] with statements we can copy-paste and you will get more and higher-quality answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you asked about `break`, this is what I meant.

An ordinary query, where all "cells" are populated with data:

```
SQL> select d.dname, e.job, e.ename, e.sal
  2  from emp e join dept d on d.deptno = e.deptno
  3  order by d.dname, e.job;

DNAME          JOB       ENAME             SAL
-------------- --------- ---------- ----------
ACCOUNTING     CLERK     MILLER           1300
ACCOUNTING     MANAGER   CLARK            2450
ACCOUNTING     PRESIDENT KING             5000
RESEARCH       ANALYST   SCOTT            3000
RESEARCH       ANALYST   FORD             3000
RESEARCH       CLERK     ADAMS            1100
RESEARCH       CLERK     SMITH             840
RESEARCH       MANAGER   JONES            2975
SALES          CLERK     JAMES             950
SALES          MANAGER   BLAKE            2850
SALES          SALESMAN  MARTIN           1250
SALES          SALESMAN  WARD             1250
SALES          SALESMAN  ALLEN            1600
SALES          SALESMAN  TURNER           1500

14 rows selected.
```

If you put a break on e.g. department name and job, you get something that looks like result you need:

```
SQL> spool stefek.csv
SQL> break on dname on job
SQL> select d.dname, e.job, e.ename, e.sal
  2  from emp e join dept d on d.deptno = e.deptno
  3  order by d.dname, e.job;

DNAME          JOB       ENAME             SAL
-------------- --------- ---------- ----------
ACCOUNTING     CLERK     MILLER           1300
               MANAGER   CLARK            2450
               PRESIDENT KING             5000
RESEARCH       ANALYST   SCOTT            3000
                         FORD             3000
               CLERK     ADAMS            1100
                         SMITH             840
               MANAGER   JONES            2975
SALES          CLERK     JAMES             950
               MANAGER   BLAKE            2850
               SALESMAN  MARTIN           1250
                         WARD             1250
                         ALLEN            1600
                         TURNER           1500

14 rows selected.

SQL> spool off
SQL>
```

If you open that file in Excel, you get this:

1. in ver. 2016, go to "Data - From text" and follow the wizard
2. choose "Fixed width"
3. move separator lines where necessary
4. see the result

[image]

---

## Connecting to SQL*Plus

You should know username, password and database you're connecting to. For example, I'm scanning my TNSNAMES.ORA file with the `mctnsping` utility (written by Michel Cadot; it doesn't require Oracle client to work. You can find it on  [OraFAQ Forum](http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/207777/)). Or, if you have TNSPING available, use it:

```
C:\Temp>mctnsping orcl

McTnsping Utility by Michel Cadot: Version 2021.12.03 on 20-PRO-2022 14:09:02

Copyright (c) Michel Cadot, 2016-2021. All rights reserved.

Using ping version 11

Used parameter files:
C:\Users\littlefoot\Documents\sqlnet.ora
C:\Users\littlefoot\Documents\tnsnames.ora

Found tnsnames.ora entry:
(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=db_orcl)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcl)))

Attempting to contact db_orcl:1521
OK (46 msec)
```

Now, use data you gathered; connect string is in format of `@database_server:port/service_name`:

```
C:\Temp>sqlplus scott/tiger@db_orcl:1521/orcl

SQL*Plus: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Uto Pro 20 14:09:17 2022
Version 18.5.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP,
Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
   
SQL> select * from dual;

D
-
X

SQL>
```

Comment: can you help me with connecting to SQL*Plus. I am connecting to Oracle XE from SQL developer as SYS with SYSDBA role and it works, but when I am trying to do the same from command prompt it says ORA-12638: Credential retrieval failed. What am I doing wrong

Comment: Well, you most probably shouldn't be using SYS nor SYSTEM for such things. They *own* the database so - if you do something *terribly wrong*, you'll destroy the database. Create your own user (or use one of predefined, such as SCOTT or HR if they exist) and do whatever you're doing in that schema. As of your problems while connecting to SQL*Plus, see edited answer.

Comment: I managed to connect. Now I have just a quick question about query. I used `break on ord_no on LS_PROD_FAMILY_NAME and after that I put in query, from tmp_product_family and order by ord_no;` But the output looks like this and is not the way yours was [link](https://imgur.com/a/qCdwc4Y)

Comment: That's because columns are too wide. You can (should?) "shorten" them by using the COL command, e.g. `col ename format a15` (which means that it would then be 15 characters wide). Also, set longer line size by  e.g. `set linesize 200`. Wouldn't harm if you actually read about SQL*Plus Reporting to see what's being offered.

Comment: I hope this is the last question. I have one number column and other columns are texts (strings, varchar whichever you like). Now I am using `col ord_no format 99999 col ls_prod_area format a200` so I am formatting number to 99999 and all other columns to 200 characters. the problem is when I want to do Data from CSV in Excel I cannot put fixed width because it is not fixed. Columns are separated by | and I would use that but in output it looks like this [link](https://imgur.com/a/SVesSQd). As you see data is all over the place.These are commands[link](https://imgur.com/a/6H3KliG).

Comment: Sorry, can't access Imgur at the moment. It is a simple task to do it with a column separator (you'd use e.g. `set colsep "|"`), but it is in vain if you use BREAK because everything is shifted *left* to fill empty spaces. In that case, you'll have to **fix** column width for every column. How? Right-pad strings with spaces, e.g. `select rpad(name, 200, ' ')`. That should let you use the "Fixed width" and separate columns.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250581/discussion-between-goddamnlawyer-and-littlefoot).

Comment: Is it possible for columns not to be moved from where their values should be when using break on command? I managed to get the output right, but the column values are moved when break happens e.g. value of column that should be under ls_brand_name is under ls_prod_family_name etc. Is there any way to fix that? @Littlefoot

Comment: Unfortunately, I wouldn't know.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the minimal sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (a, b, c, d ) AS
  SELECT 'A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A2', 'B1', 'C2', 'D1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A3', 'B2', 'C2', 'D1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A4', 'B3', 'C2', 'D1' FROM DUAL;
```

and you want to shuffle the data up the rows so that duplicates are not displayed then you can rank the values in each column, unpivot and then re-pivot the data:

```sql
SELECT a, b, c, d
FROM   (
  SELECT a, b, c, d,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY a) AS a_rnk,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY b) AS b_rnk,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY c) AS c_rnk,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY d) AS d_rnk
  FROM   table_name
)
UNPIVOT (
  (value, rnk) FOR key IN (
    (a, a_rnk) AS 'A',
    (b, b_rnk) AS 'B',
    (c, c_rnk) AS 'C',
    (d, d_rnk) AS 'D'
  )
)
PIVOT (
  MAX(value) FOR key IN ('A' AS a, 'B' AS b, 'C' AS c, 'D' AS d)
)
ORDER BY rnk
```

Which outputs:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | B1 | C1 | D1 |
| A2 | B2 | C2 | *null* |
| A3 | B3 | *null* | *null* |
| A4 | *null* | *null* | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kXwsqmEg)

Answer (score 0):

I actually managed to do it by changing the delimiter from '|' to Fixed width of 0, 800, 1000, 1200 etc. That worked fine now so thank you all for your effort. I need a little bit more tuning with the break on command but I think this solved all my future reporting problems. Huge thanks to @Littlefoot, kudos for making my life easier.

[Solved import from Text/CSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unu4I.png)

Additionally to using SQL*Plus and break on command, I managed to the same thing in SQL Developer with LAG function and some partition by clause, and then comparing column values to previous rows.

Something like this:

```sql
SELECT ord_no,case when ls_prod_area=prev_ls_prod_area then null else ls_prod_area end,case when ls_prod_family_name=prev_ls_prod_family_name then null else ls_prod_family_name end,ls_prod_family_code,case when ls_prod_generic_name=prev_ls_prod_generic_name then null else ls_prod_generic_name end,case when ls_brand_name=prev_ls_brand_name then null else ls_brand_name end,ls_reference_prod,ls_description,case when ls_atc_code=prev_ls_atc_code then null else ls_atc_code end,case when ls_atc_desc=prev_ls_atc_desc then null else ls_atc_desc end,case when ls_indication=prev_ls_indication then null else ls_indication end,case when ls_ind_meddra_lvl=prev_ls_ind_meddra_lvl then null else ls_ind_meddra_lvl end,case when ls_ind_meddra_ver=prev_ls_ind_meddra_ver then null else ls_ind_meddra_ver end,case when ls_ind_meddra_code=prev_ls_ind_meddra_code then null else ls_ind_meddra_code end
  FROM (
SELECT ord_no,ls_prod_area,ls_prod_family_name,ls_prod_family_code,ls_prod_generic_name,ls_brand_name,ls_reference_prod,ls_description,ls_atc_code,ls_atc_desc,ls_indication,ls_ind_meddra_lvl,ls_ind_meddra_ver,ls_ind_meddra_code,
       LAG( ls_prod_area, 1 ) OVER ( PARTITION BY ord_no ORDER BY ord_no, ls_brand_name, LS_ATC_CODE desc, LS_ATC_DESC, LS_INDICATION, LS_IND_MEDDRA_LVL nulls last, LS_IND_MEDDRA_VER nulls last, LS_IND_MEDDRA_CODE) AS prev_ls_prod_area,
       LAG( ls_prod_family_name, 1 ) OVER ( PARTITION BY ord_no ORDER BY ord_no, ls_brand_name, LS_ATC_CODE desc, LS_ATC_DESC, LS_INDICATION, LS_IND_MEDDRA_LVL nulls last, LS_IND_MEDDRA_VER nulls last, LS_IND_MEDDRA_CODE ) AS prev_ls_prod_family_name,
       LAG( ls_prod_generic_name, 1 ) OVER ( PARTITION BY ord_no ORDER BY ord_no, ls_brand_name, LS_ATC_CODE desc, LS_ATC_DESC, LS_INDICATION, LS_IND_MEDDRA_LVL nulls last, LS_IND_MEDDRA_VER nulls last, LS_IND_MEDDRA_CODE ) AS prev_ls_prod_generic_name,
        LAG( ls_brand_name, 1 ) OVER ( PARTITION BY ord_no ORDER BY ord_no, ls_brand_name, LS_ATC_CODE desc, LS_ATC_DESC, LS_INDICATION, LS_IND_MEDDRA_LVL nulls last, LS_IND_MEDDRA_VER nulls last, LS_IND_MEDDRA_CODE ) AS prev_ls_brand_name,
        LAG( ls_atc_code, 1 ) OVER ( PARTITION BY ord_no ORDER BY ord_no, ls_brand_name, LS_ATC_CODE desc, LS_ATC_DESC, LS_INDICATION, LS_IND_MEDDRA_LVL nulls last, LS_IND_MEDDRA_VER nulls last, LS_IND_MEDDRA_CODE ) AS prev_ls_atc_code,
        LAG( ls_atc_desc, 1 ) OVER ( PARTITION BY ord_no ORDER BY ord_no, ls_brand_name, LS_ATC_CODE desc, LS_ATC_DESC, LS_INDICATION, LS_IND_MEDDRA_LVL nulls last, LS_IND_MEDDRA_VER nulls last, LS_IND_MEDDRA_CODE ) AS prev_ls_atc_desc,
        LAG( ls_indication, 1 ) OVER ( PARTITION BY ord_no ORDER BY ord_no, ls_brand_name, LS_ATC_CODE desc, LS_ATC_DESC, LS_INDICATION, LS_IND_MEDDRA_LVL nulls last, LS_IND_MEDDRA_VER nulls last, LS_IND_MEDDRA_CODE ) AS prev_ls_indication,
        LAG( ls_ind_meddra_lvl, 1 ) OVER ( PARTITION BY ord_no ORDER BY ord_no, ls_brand_name, LS_ATC_CODE desc, LS_ATC_DESC, LS_INDICATION, LS_IND_MEDDRA_LVL nulls last, LS_IND_MEDDRA_VER nulls last, LS_IND_MEDDRA_CODE ) AS prev_ls_ind_meddra_lvl,
        LAG( ls_ind_meddra_ver, 1 ) OVER ( PARTITION BY ord_no ORDER BY ord_no, ls_brand_name, LS_ATC_CODE desc, LS_ATC_DESC, LS_INDICATION, LS_IND_MEDDRA_LVL nulls last, LS_IND_MEDDRA_VER nulls last, LS_IND_MEDDRA_CODE ) AS prev_ls_ind_meddra_ver,
        LAG( ls_ind_meddra_code, 1 ) OVER ( PARTITION BY ord_no ORDER BY ord_no, ls_brand_name, LS_ATC_CODE desc, LS_ATC_DESC, LS_INDICATION, LS_IND_MEDDRA_LVL nulls last, LS_IND_MEDDRA_VER nulls last, LS_IND_MEDDRA_CODE ) AS prev_ls_ind_meddra_code
        FROM tmp_product_family);
```

Comment: No problem, I'm glad you made it work.